# Error message: You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a windows forms application which opens two excel files and compare the cell content.

> Recently I'm experiencing the following error in some machines that
>   this application is installed in.

[image]

> In other machines this works perfectly fine.

I've checked folder permissions / file permissions / Excel and Windows versions of the machines that runs this program. Nothing seems to work for me and sort out the problem as a whole.

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for reading and writing to my excel files.

To open the excel files I'm using the following code.

```
        bool inputSheetReadStatus = false;
        DialogResult dialogResultInputSheet = openFileDialog_InputSheet.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogResultInputSheet == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            InputSheetFullPath = openFileDialog_InputSheet.FileName;
            InputSheetFileName = openFileDialog_InputSheet.SafeFileName;
            InputSheetFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(InputSheetFullPath);

            try
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp_InputSheet = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook_InputSheet = xlApp_InputSheet.Workbooks.Open(InputSheetFullPath);
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet_InputSheet = xlWorkbook_InputSheet.Sheets["CO"];
                Excel.Range xlRange_InputSheet = xlWorksheet_InputSheet.UsedRange;

                string InputSheetDocumentValidationStringValue = xlRange_InputSheet.Cells[cosv.InputSheet_CO_Style_Label_Row, cosv.InputSheet_CO_Style_Label_Col].Value2.ToString().Trim();

                if (InputSheetDocumentValidationStringValue.ToUpper() == cosv.InputSheet_CO_Validation_String)
                {

                // If valid excel file the manipulation logic goes here

                }
             }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
            }
         }
```

Any thoughts or ideas for me to try out in order to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

I tested this application in **Windows 7 / 8 / 10 machines with excel versions 16 and 17** using the **same two files**. Out of the **10** machines I tested this, in **4 machines my application worked**. In **6 machines my application displayed this error message**.

Comment: Most probably the owner/administrator of the file does not want his file to be opened. Have you contacted him/her?

Comment: The same file works in some machines. And its not merely a single file that fails. If it fails, it fails for any excel file that I try to upload to the application. @Vityata

Comment: Is this single file with an extension `xlsm` or `xlsb`?

Comment: did u try to  open the file manually? what is happened?

Comment: For any given instance when I run the application I upload 2 files. One after the other. If the first upload succeeds then the 2nd file is prompted to be uploaded and selected by the user. That's how the application works. The users normally upload .xlsx and .xls files and sometimes .xlsm files.

Comment: I can open files manually. It works.

Comment: _"an ASP.NET windows forms application"_ does not exist. And it kind of matters here.

Comment: I can't figure out what your app is doing here. Do you upload to a Web app? If so, is the error on the client or on the server?

Comment: When a user runs the application, first the user is supposed to upload the 1st excel file with the data. (In a standard format). Then the system reads the data in the excel to a data table. If everything is as expected then the application asks the user to upload the 2nd file with data. (In a standard format). Then the system reads the data in the 2nd excel to a data table. Now the system compares the data in the tow data tables and exports a 3rd excel file highlighting the differences in the data in the 1st and the 2nd excel file.

Comment: This application is installed in the users computer. It doesn't upload excels to any web application or anything of the sort. It just reads and compares the two files. But in some machines as soon as I select the 1st file, I get the attached error message.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is an application I developed using visual studio 2017 BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the application with administrative rights.